# FFT for equations that have terms with different exponents

Tags: algorithm, fft

I am new to FFTs so I am slightly confused on some concepts. So far the FFT examples I've seen for equation multiplication involve equations with consecutive exponents (i.e. `A(x) = 1 + 3x + 5x^2 +...` and `B(x) = 4 + 6x + 9x^2 + ...` and `C(x) = A(x)*B(x)`). However, it is possible to use FFT on two equations that do not have equal exponents? For example, is it possible to use FFT to multiply:

```
A(x) = 1 + 3x^2 + 9x^8
```

and

```
B(x) = 5x + 6 x^3 + 10x^8
```

in `O(nlogn)` time?

If not, are there any cases where the runtime will be `O(nlogn)`? For example, if the number of terms in the product is `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`?

Even if the runtime is more than `O(nlogn)`, how can we use FFT to minimize the runtime?

Comment: also if your multiplicants are integer you can use NTT instead of DFFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to use **DFFT** on non equal exponent polynomials...

the missing exponents are just multiplied by `0` which is also a number... just rewrite your polynomials:

```
A(x) = 1 + 3x^2 + 9x^8
B(x) = 5x + 6x^3 + 10x^8
```

to something like this:

```
A(x) = 1x^0 + 0x^1 + 3x^2 + 0x^3 + 0x^4+ 0x^5+ 0x^6+ 0x^7 +  9x^8
B(x) = 0x^0 + 5x^1 + 0x^2 + 6x^3 + 0x^4+ 0x^5+ 0x^6+ 0x^7 + 10x^8
```

so your vectors for **DFFT** are:

```
A = (1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0, 9)
B = (0,5,0,6,0,0,0,0,10)
```

add zero's so the vector is the correct result size (max A exponent +1 + max B exponent +1) and also round up to closest power of `2` for **DFFT** usage so original sizes are `9,9 -> 9+9 -> 18 -> round up -> 32`

```
A = (1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0, 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
B = (0,5,0,6,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
//  |    original      | correct result  |    nearest power of 2      |
```

and do the **DFFT** stuff you want ... I assume you want to do something like this:

```
A' = DFFT(A)
B' = DFFT(B)
C(i)' = A'(i) * B'(i)   // i=0..n-1
C= IDFFT(C')
```

which is `O(n*log(n))`. **Do not forget** that if you use **DFFT** (not DFT) **n = 32** and not 18 !!! because `n` must be power of `2` for fast algorithm of **DFT** also if you want performance improvements than look at the **DFFT** weight matrices for **DFFT(A),DFFT(B)** they are the same so no need to compute them twice ...