# Pairs from a dense set: Determine histogram of sums much faster than Ο(n²)

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

**Given a set *S* of *n* natural numbers below 9*n*/7, how can one establish the number of pairs summing to every number from 0 to 18*n*/7?** (2-combinations, 3 < *n*)
Let *m* be the maximum value of elements in *S*.
If *m* was *n*-1, the sequence of counts of pairs summing up to ( 0, 1,  … 18*n*/7 ) would be [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, … m/2, m/2, (*m*+2)/2, m/2, m/2, (*m*-2)/2, … 2, 1, 1, 0, …, 0 ] for odd *n*, or [ 0, 1, 1, 2, … (*n*-2)/2, (*n*-2)/2, *n*/2, *n*/2, *n*/2, (*n*-2)/2, (*n*-2)/2, (*n*-4)/2, … 2, 1, 1, 0, …, 0 ] for even *n*.
It isn't too difficult to establish the counts if *n* is an element of S (and one of the numbers below isn't), as is nesting two loops and just counting the occurrences of each sum - Ο(n²):

How can one establish a *histogram of pair sums* (much) faster than Ο(n²)?
(Does knowing *m* < 9*n*/7 help?
Is it notably harder for 9*n*/2 < *m* ((semi-)sparse set)?)

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. You may want to try to explain more clearly.

Comment: @Richard I'd be glad to (be able to). It might be helpful if you pointed out something specific to be unclear.

Comment: As I already mentioned, it doesn't seem that the bounds are very helpful to find a fast algorithm. But I really don't know is it possible to avoid fourier transform and get better than O(n log n), or just something better than n^1.5. It is interesting.

Comment: @Spektre, what you are saying makes no sense. After all DFT takes n log n, I really and again really don't see how sorting can help? About your math skill, I think you should ask it in a new thread and more precisely. This comment is the answer to the comment on amit's answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri for FFT approach youre right but all of the stuff is important for the non FFT approaches which is all this about... I did not ask for help (just stated so it is clear I could be wrong)

Comment: @Spektre, This is what you wrote: "BTW I wanted to do the DFT/NTT approach too but cant make it work ". It means two things: 1. You are eager to use FFT, 2. You don't know how to do it. You also wrote: "I can do the convolution easily (using it for bignum multiplication) but not the modular convolution". Sorry I really don't understand you.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri you need to read the linked QA [
Alternate way to compute product of pairwise sums mod 10^9+7 faster than O(N^2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41531391/2521214) for that. btw I just got it to work with NTT and the modular convolution. And also found out what was the problem with my FFT approach.

Comment: @Spektre, I don't see how that Q&A is related to advantage of sorting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in `O(nlogn)`, using Fourier transformation.

First recall that a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is defined as:

```
(h*g)[n] = sum { h[n-i] + f[i] | i in Z }
```

And note that a convolution on the [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the data is exactly what you want. Convolution can be calculated in `O(nlogn)` using [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Convolution_theorem).

This gives the basic following algorithm:

1. Create histogram with has/tree based map. Let it be h.
2. using fourier transform to find (h*h).

Comment: (:Dang. I thought I skilfully avoided mentioning convolution, as I'm looking for ideas for an [_Alternate_ way to compute product of pairwise sums](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41531391/3789665).:)

Comment: @greybeard First, that was not the question... Second, by one more step you simply multiply the pairs needed, which should be efficient using smart exponent algorithm.

Comment: `First, [an Alternate way to compute product of pairwise sums] was not [How can one establish a histogram of pair sums fast]` indeed. Someone even asked a separate question. `Second…` That looks a sketch of the reference approach the question linked above searches alternatives to.

Comment: (`Create histogram with [hash]/tree based map` - or do a counting sort, considering there are not much more possible values than there are elements.)

Comment: @greybeard, counting sort won't help much, as per fourier transform one does not need it. Also if it was helpful, in the general problem one could first sort in n log n and then do the rest. The bottleneck is not about sorting. But if you want to avoid DFT then just use O(n^1.6) method based on polynomial multiplications.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: "counting sort" of the elements to establish amit's `h`, not of the sums.

Comment: @greybeard, At any moment in the general algorithm you can do a O(n log n) sorting on whatever you want. I don't see any point of counting sort. Actually I don't see how sorting can play any role at all (having n logn algorithm in hand).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri the histogram (counting,or sorting) of `h` is just to speed up the convolution `h*g` as some elements are duplicate so they can be handled as power of a single value lowering the `n` for the `O(n^2)` process. And also working with exponents instead of values is faster for the convolution operation itself because the task this is targeted on is done on modular arithmetics `GF(1000000009)` where is significantly slower to `modmul,modpow` values then combining exponents (which can be done with simple `int` arithmetics directly).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri  The `m` limit is important so we can do bucket sort/histogram in `O(n)`. BTW I wanted to do the **DFT/NTT** approach too but cant make it work ... I can do the convolution easily (using it for bignum multiplication) but not the modular convolution ... My math skills are not very good in number theory an finite fields so I must have done something wrong somewhere or ignore some theorem ... still trying though :)